# A game involving total heads and tails from a weighted coin

Tags: probability

Recently I considered the following game:

Consider a coin weighted so that $P(H) = p$. Player A flips the coin $N$ times, counting each heads as a win, and player B counts each tails as a win. After $N$ flips, the two players swap and flip $N$ more times or until a player has reached a total of $N+1$ wins, so that now player A counts tails and player B counts heads, adding them to their previous total. If the game reaches a final score of $N$ to $N$, flip a fair coin to decide the winner.

I am trying to compute the probability of player A winning depending on $p$. The game is obviously biased, since starting first when $p>1/2$ gives you a guaranteed $N$ flips of the coin biased in your favor, whereas player B has potentially fewer flips when the coin favors them after you swap since the game can end early.

The first half of the game and the tie condition are pretty easy to break down but I am having a hard time getting at the second half. So far I have something like this:

Let $A_1$ and $A_2$ denote the number of wins attained by player A in the first $N$ flips, and the second half of the game, respectively, then we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
P(A\ wins) &= \sum_{k=1}^NP(A_1 = k)P(A \ wins|A_1=k) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^NP(A_1 = k)\left[\frac{1}{2}P(X_2 = N-k) + P(A \ wins \ outright|A_1=k)\right]
\end{aligned}
$$

$P(A_1=k)$ and $P(A_2 = N-k)$ are both easily expressible in terms of binomial distributions since the number of flips in the first half is fixed and all $N$ flips in the second half would have to be played out to result in a draw. I am unsure on the best way to handle the other probability of player A attaining $N+1$ points before player B wins outright or brings it to a draw. I played around a bit with some simple binomial and negative binomial stuff but nothing seemed to give reasonable answers. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a simple spreadsheet for some short games ($N=2$, $N=3$, $N=4$) with $p = 3/4$ and found that the game was perfectly fair in each case: A and B each win the overall game with probability $1/2.$ So the game is not so obviously biased after all.

Assume $p > 1/2$ and consider a game similar to the one in the question except that the game does not stop until the unfair coin has been flipped $2N$ times. Then whoever has the most wins is the overall winner, except that in the case where there is a tie we break it by flipping a fair coin.

In this revised game, except in the tie-breaking scenario, whoever wins the overall game must have reached $N+1$ wins some time during the period when the coin favored player B. In the original game they would have won instantly at that time, but in the revised game they continue tossing the coin even though the winner is already a foregone conclusion.

In other words, both games have the same probabilities of a win for player A,
and likewise for B.

So we can just consider the second game, which has $N$ flips favoring A and $N$ favoring $B.$ "Obviously" this game is not biased.